# How to use LSTM to make prediction with both feature from the past and the current ones?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Suppose I have a data frame like the following, Discount is calculated from `selling price/list price`, unit_sales is the number of items sold on that day.

[image]

If I am going to use LSTM to make sales prediction for the next day (data in the green box), based on the past 3 days of sales and discount (data frame in the red box), **plus the discount to be applied on the next day (data frame in the purple box)**, how should I reshape the dataframe?
[image]

This could be really easy if I don't have to consider about the discount at the current or future time step, I would just reshape it to (# of samples - 3, 3, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way - instead of having one input into your model you can have 2: discount/sales pairs for the past 3 days with the shape (# of samples -3, 3, 2) as you suggested and another one with the shape (1,) which corresponds to the current discount. You can run the previous 3 days through the LSTM and concatenate the current discount to the output of LSTM. Using functional API it will look like this:

```
inp_past=Input((3,2))
lstm=LSTM(32)(inp_past)
inp_now=Input((1,))
concatenation= concatenate([inp_now,lstm])
output=Dense(1)(concatenation
```

Does this help you a little bit?

Comment: Sure it helps! Let me try it.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind, if I want to do multistep forecasting, and I make the LSTM layer return_sequences setting to true, should I use the same function (concatenate) to merge the input (3, 1) and output from the first LSTM?

Comment: It really depends... You might want to reshape the discount  information via Repeat command or do it manually when you generate the data. You can only concatenate things of the same dimensionality so if your past discount/sales data has shape (3,2) then discount will have to be (3,1)

Comment: Sorry about my poor English expression, but you had answered what I meant to ask, thank you very much

Comment: Good to hear! Mark it is answered please